# Add new value to list as dictionary value in python

Tags: python

I am doing right now a python's course and I have an exercise I do not get the answer at all. I would like you to help me with this easy problem.

The **problem** is:
Users can belong to multiple groups. Fill in the blanks to return a `dictionary` with the users as keys and a list of their groups as values.

I tried to do the exercise but the computer doesn't recognize my answer as valid. I think it is because the `brackets`.

Here is my code:-

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
   user_groups = {}
    for group, user in group_dictionary.items():
    
        for user in user:
            if user not in user_groups:
                user_groups[user] = group
            else:
                
                x = user_groups[user]
                new_group={}
                new_group = {user: [x,group]}
                
                user_groups.update(new_group)
                
    return(user_groups)
print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

---

And I get

```
{'admin': [['local', 'public'], 'administrator'], 'userA': 'local', 'userB': 'public'}
```

I tried to avoid the brackets too with this code instead

---

```
> new_group = {user: [x,group]}
> 
> new_group = {user: [str(x).lstrip('[').rstrip(']'),group]}
```

This time I get:

```
{'admin': ["'local', 'public'", 'administrator'], 'userA': 'local', 'userB': 'public'}
```

Both times were not valid.

Is there a better way?

Thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: What kind of result you want to get if  the  count of `group` for `userA` is only 1? `["local"]` or `local`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all

```
for user in user:
```

Will overwrite the iteration variable. Don't do this.

Second:

```
user_groups[user] = group
```

This will map the user to the group. Instead you can create the list of groups here directly with

```
user_groups[user] = [group] # single element list
```

Finally:

```
x = user_groups[user]
new_group={}
new_group = {user: [x,group]}
user_groups.update(new_group)
```

None of this is required. You can simply append the new group to the existing users list with:

```
user_groups[user].append(group)
```

Which gives us:

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():

        for user in users:
            if user not in user_groups:
                user_groups[user] = [group]
            else:
                user_groups[user].append(group)
    return user_groups


print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
                       "public": ["admin", "userB"],
                       "administrator": ["admin"]}))
```

Ouput:

```
{'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have just start to study and I have quite a lot of newbie mistakes like the for loop. I really tried to create a list just as you said, but I couldn't. I forgot the [] in group and after that when I tried to use .append(group) it said syntax error. But now I understand how to do it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict to achieve this and avoid usage of the if-else condition

```
from  collections import defaultdict

def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = defaultdict(list)
    for group, users in group_dictionary.items():

        for user in users:
            user_groups[user].append(group)
    return user_groups  # return dict(user_groups) if you want it to be returned in dict format


print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
                       "public": ["admin", "userB"],
                       "administrator": ["admin" ]}))
```